# Does USB-attached fan create large power demand on laptop?

Tags: laptop, fan

Does an externally-attached USB fan create a heavy power draw on the laptop?

Comment: What do you mean by "heavy power draw"? Whether it damage laptop / make battery drain faster? Please also add a bit of background to your question. Currently it's too broad and likely to be closed.

Comment: Depends on the fan. You have not given us enough information to answer your question.

Comment: Define "Large power draw"

Comment: Measure the current draw with a USB volt & amp meter

Answer (score 1):

This depends largely on two factors:

**1. The fan.**

How much current will it (try to) draw? Depending on how many watts the fan is rated for, the current drain doesn't need to be much.

**2. The USB port**

A USB3.0 port, if my memory serves me right, has a max output of 900mA. USB2.0 has 500mA.

Based the above two, let's presume a fan that will draw as much current it is allowed to from a USB3 port: 900mA x 5V = **4.5W**, which is what I would consider "not much".

Comment: USB 1.1 was 500ma, usb2 is 900ma